# Silverlight - How to navigate from a User Control to a normal page?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

If I do this inside a User Control:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Alliance.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

it says this error:

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)'

Thank you

---

Well, I solved passing the normal Page as an argument to the User Control, so I could get the NavigationService.

Comment: I tried the solution from Waleed. That solved mine...

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this for years.  The Navigation framework is a brick wall for MVVM development.  The only solutions that I've found are disgusting hacks which I refuse to use!  I don't want my pages to have any knowledge of navigation!

Answer (score 50):

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(uri);
```

Comment: What is PhoneApplicationFrame here ? In my code I have App.xaml which calls into Main.xaml
Main.xaml is UserControl and I want to use navigate from there.

Answer (score 12):

I normally use an EventHandler. Example:
in your user control, define something like

```
public event EventHandler goToThatPage;
```

that you will call in your control foe example like this:

```
goToThatPage(this, new EventArgs());
```

Then in the constructor of your MainPage.xaml.cs (if the user control is contained there) you will define:

```
uxControlName.goToThatPage+= new EventHandler(ControlGoToThatPage);
```

and somewhere in your MainPage.xaml.cs you finaly declare the action to be done:

```
    void ControlGoToThatPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/ThatPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me with a solution...and is a nice, tidy way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution for Silverlight for Windows Phone 8:

```
public Page Page { get; set; }
```

---

```
this.Loaded += delegate
{
    Page = (Application.Current.RootVisual as Frame).Content as Page;
};
```

---

```
Page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Alliance.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1):

NavigationService is a class. Navigate is a method you can call on instances of that class. It is not a static method you can call from outside an object reference.

Basically you need to get the current NavigationService for the current page. This link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.aspx should help.

Answer (score 1):

NavigationService is a property of the page object in Silverlight, which is why you are getting this error. It is not a property of a UserControl in Silverlight.

The following are a few options which will be able to solve the issue you're seeing.

1. Treat the usercontrol as a control. Give it an event which it will fire when the button is clicked. The page can listen for that event and handle the navigation when it fires.
2. You can either allow your page access to its parent or pass the NavigationService from the page to the usercontrol.
3. You can also set this up using messaging, but that would be more complicated.Many MVVM frameworks have messaging features. [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) has it.

Comment: well, in the UserControl, I have a button, when it is clicked, I navigate to another page.

Comment: Can you use a HyperlinkButton instead of the regular button?

Comment: I would say don't navigate from the control but rather give an event to the page and allow the page to navigate. Your control should only offer input not control navigation.

Answer (score 0):

```
((Frame)(Application.Current.RootVisual as MainPage).FindName("ContentFrame"))
    .Navigate(new Uri("Page Name", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was also in the same situation on a Silverlight app. I wanted to do something similar to Deepak's answer, but I couldn't figure it out for the longest time why it didn't work in my case.

Turns out I needed to call refresh, and not navigate; because I originally thought that navigate would reload the page if the URI is the same as the current page. Forgive my beginner-ness.

```
(((Application.Current.RootVisual as MainPage).ContentFrame as Frame).Content as Page).NavigationService.Refresh();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        if(Application.Current.RootVisual is Page)
        {
            ((Page) (Application.Current.RootVisual)).NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
        }
```