# Invoking a UI screen from within a class library function in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, class-library

I have recently started on Windows 7 app development, and I am stuck on the problem described below. Any help is greatly appreciated!!.

I am writing a WP7 class library function, which will be called from a Windows phone application. I want to be able to show a new screen to the user, after the function call has been made, invoked from the *class library function.* I also want this screen to be integrated with rest of the application UI properly. Like for ex., Clicking the back button on the UI screen, should take me to the UI screen that was present, before the call was made.

This WP7 class library has to be linked as a compiled library with the windows phone application. So keeping that in mind, I have following two questions.

1) Is it even possible, to launch a UI screen from a class library in Windows phone 7? If not, what else I could do here?

2) Is it possible to integrate this screen with rest of the application UI flow as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can include XAML pages in your library. To do that you have to include **.pdb** file which is generated along with the **.dll** for your library class. Copy both the **.dll** and **.pdb** file to your project and add reference to the **.dll**.

Comment: pdb? Debug symbols? This is normally not needed.

Comment: 2) Why would you copy the dll to your project? You are adding a reference to a dll which might be either in GAC or in a file, for example in the bin folder of the dll project. VS will do the rest and produce xap installer that includes the referenced dll.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes. If you ever programmed Win32, then I understand your concerns. Handling UI in a dll was a bit problematic.

First to the class selection:

Popup class can be used to overlap current screen content. Its basic disadvantage is that it is not HW accelerated, hence unsuitable for complex screens or animations.

A better solution might be to store PhoneApplicationPage in your library (assembly). The result is the same as if the page was defined in the application assembly. [This article](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jgarland/archive/2011/02/16/silverlight-for-windows-phone-programming-tip-navigation.aspx) describes how to navigate to another assembly.

When you navigate to another page (which is incidentally stored in another assembly), there is no shared UI context such as the main application window in Win32. The pages themselves are fully independent. URI of the first page is written in the manifest file. (Part of the xap file.) The application decides when to go to another page. Same as for browsers.

From the technical point of view:

Your class library produces an assembly (dll). This dll contains a) code (similarly to old good Win32 dlls), b) Xaml (exact copy of the Xaml code used in your library). It is the same as for your main assembly.

When you add a reference to the class library, that dll will be added to the xap file, i.e. to the installer. Go to your bin folder and look into the xap file. It is trivial as it is just a zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I know how to compile XAML pages along with the class library code. The problem I was facing is, how to invoke a UI screen(External_UI) from a function (present in the class library). The only solution is to execute "NavigationService.Navigate(EXTERNAL_UI_URL)". But I can't access NavigationService object without the main application passing this object to the class library function as a param. This post explains how to access pages present in external assembly-http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/navigating-to-pages-in-different-assembly-in-windows-phone-7/

Comment: "NavigationService object"? What you mean by that? NavigationService.Navigate() is a static method. If you want to pass any data, then you have to do it in textual form using URI syntax.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not a static method. References - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730245/silverlight-how-to-navigate-from-a-user-control-to-a-normal-page/3730445#3730445 (and the Question). Also check out the method syntax code in c# here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591053(v=vs.95).aspx. There is no static keyword in that signature.

Comment: Ok, my bad. But stil... If you create a PhoneApplicationPage in an external assembly, it has NavigationService. You can navigate to that page from main assembly and you can navigate from that page to yet another page. The condition is that the external assembly is added to the project references. (Visual Studio > Project > References > Right click...)

Comment: You can navigate from an external assembly even if it does not create the page. Just get the current page from (PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual, take its Content property and cast it to PhoneApplicationPage.