# Windows Phone - event handler for lost network connection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, connectivity

I want to everytime when user lost his network connection to go to main page of application. I found that `DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged`is what I am looking for but I am not sure what exactly should I add as code in method and how it exactly works. When I add eventhandler in main page than it works for whole application? And can I have in that method `NavigationService` with `Navigate` method? I am thinking that I someway check if I am not on `MainPage.xaml` then I would navigate to this page and if yes, then I call other code (for setting visibility on some controls and so). Is this good way of doing this? Can I check in code which is active page? Thanks

Comment: you can subscribe in App.xaml.cs file

Comment: But I can't use NavigationService.Navigate in App.xaml.cs.

Comment: Take a look on this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730245/silverlight-how-to-navigate-from-a-user-control-to-a-normal-page/4946688#4946688

Answer (score 1):

In your App class there is a line:

```
public PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }
```

You can navigate using it:

```
 private void GoToMainPage()
 {
    RootFrame(new Uri("View/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What Anton said was correct, as you can easily reference that RootFrame from anywhere in your code which will give you the same capability as the NavigationService from PhoneApplicationPage, and this way you are then not restricted to just code within a page in order to navigate. Although I think he missed out on the .Navigate method call:

```
RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("View/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

And also you would want to reference the RootFrame in such way:

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(...)
```

Comment: I got "Invalid cross-thread access." error and when I use Dispatche.BeginInvoke my app just crash.

Comment: With dispatcher I got this error: "No Fragment support right now"

Answer (score 0):

i do:

```
    private bool InternetIsAvailable()
    {
        if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("No tienes conexión de internet.");

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Tienes conexión de internet.");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

but, you can use this class [NetworkChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx) and see the method or event NetworkAvailabilityChanged